# Can HTTPWebRequest causes WCF to go down?

Tags: c#, .net

I have an application that hosts its own WCF web service.  I have the watchdog function below which runs every 5 seconds to ensure the web service is alive by just checking the web service's wsdl URL.

```
        public override bool IsConnected()
        {
            bool bRet = false;
            try
            {
               var Request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Settings.Default.DismissWebService + "?wsdl");
               var response = (HttpWebResponse)Request.GetResponse();

               if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
               {
                   bRet = true;
               }
               else
               {
                   bRet = false;
               }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
               _logger.Error(ex.Message,ex);
               bRet = false;
            }

            return bRet;
        }
```

I know I made a doo doo here, as I should close out the HttpWebResponse by doing

```
using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)Request.GetResponse())
{
   //Do something.
}
```

However, could this be the root cause of the WCF web service get shut down after 3 days of running?  The reason I came up with that assumption is looking at the [GetResponse doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.getresponse.aspx) , it states that

> You must call the Close method to close the stream and release the connection. Failure to do so may cause your application to run out of connections.

Does this somehow work exactly like HTTP GET/POST attack?  also when this was happening, my application process is running with 100,000K in the processwindow.

Comment: Sure, you could run out of resources on the server because it thinks that there are too many connections open.  Besides, have you tried *after* disposing properly?  Did the problem go away?

Comment: I'm waiting for the result, as the original issue occurs after 3 to 6 days :(.  By the way when you say resources, you're talking about the connection ect, not the memory number I see in the window process window right?